# W3C unable to validate

Tags: utf-8, w3c-validation

Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 1200 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

The error was: utf8 "\xD8" does not map to Unicode 
i would be thankful to know what exactly should i do, my website is : http://dailysahara.com/

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as stated by the validator, is that you have some invalid UTF-8 in your document. It appears to be in the box on the left of the site with the four tabs "Tags", "Comments", "Recents", and "Popular". It shows up to me as a black square like this: �. If you remove that, you should be able to validate your site.